# Negation of several characters before pattern

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am trying to create a regex to find the following string:

```
AGK-XL.
```

Sometimes before and after this string there are other characters that are usually harmless, except if there is the following pattern before the string:

```
NOT-
```

I need to delete/ignore those cases.
This is what I have tried:

```
^[^N][^O][^T][^\-]AGK-XL\.(\s|\W|$)
```

But it only seems to match when there are exactly 4 letters in front of the string. How can I express that any other pattern besides `NOT-` before `AGK-XL.` is harmless?

Thanks for any hints.
edit: I am using regex in VBA atm.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no look-behind in VBScript regex :( Use capturing groups: `NOT-AGK-XL\.(?!\w)|(AGK-XL\.(?!\w))`.

Comment: @stribizhev hmm that works, could you formulate an answer and explain it a bit maybe?

Comment: Without knowing what you do, it is a bit difficult to answer the question, but I will post an explanation of what I mean.

Comment: @stribizhev Ok thanks. I am trying to search for these strings and then delete them in a table, that is the final purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot use fancy look-behinds, you can rely on capturing mechanism when you need to *match* something we do not want, and *match and capture* what you want. See the [*The Best Regex Trick Ever* at rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick).

However, in this case, you can match and capture `NOT-AGK-XL.` (so that you can restore it later with `$1` backreference), and only match all other occurrences of `AGK-XL.` that you will remove. Use alternation operator `|` to match both alternatives:

```
(NOT-AGK-XL\.(?!\w))|AGK-XL\.(?!\w)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bO6jZ7/2)

Note I replaced `(\s|\W|$)` with `(?!\w)` that is - IMHO - a better word boundary check.